# Expected magnitude of a vector of $n$ i.i.d. random variables as $n\to\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

Suppose that $X_i$ are i.i.d. real valued random variables with probability distribution $f(x)$ for $i=1,2,3,\ldots$.  Let $Y_n=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\right)^{1/2}$. Assuming that $\mathbb{E}\left[Y_n\right]$ converges in probability to some constant $C$ as $n\to \infty$, how would we compute $C$?

Comment: You presumably have some normalization you need - The law of large numbers tells you $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{n} \to E[X_1^2]$. So, if $E[X_1^2] > 0$, $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \to \infty$ in probability. And if $E[X_1^2]=0$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 =0$ as well.